# función .getDate en Datetimepicker jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola estoy implementando un datatimepicker jQuery de la librería de  xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/, necesito que en la línea 3 el código logre leer una fecha, que pretendo insertarle con un echo en php. hasta ahora no se como hacerlo.

no uso este lenguaje, entiendo muy poco, me entiendo más en php y css.
de ante mano muchas gracias!

```js
   jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('es');
   var logic = function( currentDateTime ){
      if( currentDateTime.Date=={value:'2019-07-24',format:'Y-m-d'}){
   this.setOptions({
     allowTimes:['11:00','12:00']
   });
      }else
   this.setOptions({
     allowTimes:['8:00','9:00','10:00']
   });
   };
   jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      onChangeDateTime:logic,
      onShow:logic,
      inline: true,
   minDate: (0),
            dayOfWeekStart: (1),
            timepicker:true,
            disabledWeekDays: [0,<?php echo $reserva['lunes']; ?>,<?php echo $reserva['martes']; ?>,<?php echo $reserva['miercoles']; ?>,<?php echo $reserva['jueves']; ?>,<?php echo $reserva['viernes']; ?>,<?php echo $reserva['sabado']; ?>],
   disabledDates: ['2019-07-23'],
   formatDate:'Y-m-d',
   format: 'Y-m-d H:i',
   formatTime: 'H:i',
   minTime: '8:00',
   maxTime: '21:00',
   step: (60),
   allowBlank: false,
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando la propiedad `value`. Información obtenida de la [Documentación](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) (En la documentación esta abajo del todo encima de los comentarios)

```
$("#datetimepicker").('getValue');
```

Comment: me toma la fecha, sin embargo, al seleccionarla en el calendario me arroja los resultados del }else{

Comment: Que fecha estas poniendo? actualiza tu código de la pregunta

Comment: ahí lo edité, así tal cual me arroja los resultados del else al dar clic en la fecha

Comment: Prueba a poner un value en el imput en vez con la api

Comment: no no nada, si le doy value al input me muestra solo esa fecha del calendario y además me restringe para ingresar nuevas fechas a la bd

Comment: Vale, entendí mal la pregunta. Pensaba que decías que querías un valor por defecto. Edito mi respuesta